# .html()/.append() only works ones, why?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, append

I'm building a mobile app suing Phonegap and Jquery mobile. I've tried to build a reusable menu, with a javascript, however I've run into a problem. The first page that uses the menu everything loads just fine, BUT the second page, that uses the same code to load it, just shows a menu without any content.

I got the following code:

This is how i insert my menu script:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="reveal" data-dismissible="false" data-position="left">
    <script src="menuContent.js"></script>
    </div>
```

This is how i build the menu in a JavaScript:

```
$( "#navpanel" ).html('<div data-role="controlgroup" id="controlgroup" data-corners="false">' +
'<a href="prisMatch.html" id="prisMatchMenuButton" data-role="button">Pris Match</a>' +
'<a href="archive.html" id="archive" data-role="button">Arkiv</a>' +
'<a href="remember.html" id="remember" data-role="button">Husk</a>' +
'<a href="about.html" id="about" data-role="button">Om</a>' +
'</div>');
```

Any help to solve this problem is much appreciated

**SOLUTION:**

Index head link to the content in the menu:

```
<script src="menuContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Page:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="reveal" data-dismissible="false" data-position="left"></div>
```

menuContent.js:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    $("#navpanel", this).html('<div data-role="controlgroup" id="controlgroup" data-corners="false">' +
        '<a href="prisMatch.html" id="prisMatchMenuButton" data-role="button">Pris Match</a>' +
        '<a href="archive.html" id="archive" data-role="button">Arkiv</a>' +
        '<a href="remember.html" id="remember" data-role="button">Husk</a>' +
        '<a href="about.html" id="about" data-role="button">Om</a>' +
        '</div>');
});
```

Comment: You will need to ensure that ids are different. So use page name with each id in menu.

Comment: how can i use the same javascript for all pages then? etc if i got 2 pages:
Page1 and Page2, with ID page1navpanel and page2navpanel. how can i load the menu script on both of them? aka what should my $( "#navpanel" ).html() be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding elements to a **panel** dynamically, you have to call `.trigger("pagecreate");` on active page after appending elements.

#### Solution 1

```
$.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate");
```

Or

```
$("#Page_id").trigger("pagecreate");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CSMX4/)**

---

#### Solution 2

Add elements before page is created `pagebeforecreate`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role=page]", function () {
  $("#navpanel", this).html('<div data-role="controlgroup" id="controlgroup" data-corners="false">' +
   '<a href="prisMatch.html" id="prisMatchMenuButton" data-role="button">Pris Match</a>' +
   '<a href="archive.html" id="archive" data-role="button">Arkiv</a>' +
   '<a href="remember.html" id="remember" data-role="button">Husk</a>' +
   '<a href="about.html" id="about" data-role="button">Om</a>' +
   '</div>');
});
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/48pNw/)

Comment: @user2408952 solution one is faster, use when you want to add items to panel on the active page.

Comment: $.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate"); still only works on the first page when i click on a button in the menu, so a new pages opens then click on menu button to open menu. The menu is empty.

Comment: @user2408952 Exactly, this works on the active. If you want to add to all pages at the same time, then use `pagebeforecreate`.

Comment: @user2408952 `$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role=page]", function () {` i forgot to add `[data-role=page]` selector. Check the updated demo.

Comment: Do i still load the script as i showed in my code? with <script src="menuContent.js"></script> inside my html code? or do i link it in my index page with the rest of my scripts?

Comment: @user2408952 in `head` of index page.

Comment: YES THANKS^^ ill put the solution in my post